# Power apps Cascading Dropdown

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I have below items in sharepoint list -

[image]

I have added two dropdown in powerapp canvas in first dropdown I am populating Values from Test column.
In the 2nd dropdown after selecting Value from 1st dropdown like A or B or C I want to populate Values from the corresponding Columns.

Any help appreciate.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In the Items property of Dropdown2,try something like below:

```
If(Dropdown1.SelectedText.Value = "A",
     List.A,
     If(Dropdown1.SelectedText.Value = "B",
      List.B,
        List.C))
```

where List is the SharePoint list